# Bulk copy part of a table to itself in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a "versioning" table of some data, where will be 1,5 million rows per version, the structure is:

```
[ID] bigint,
[version] int,
[somecolumn] int,
[anothercolumn] int,
[thirdcolumn] tinyint
```

And I constantly need to copy one version into another version like this query would do:

```
INSERT INTO myTable 
    (SELECT ID, version + 1, somecolumn, anothercolumn, thirdcolumn 
     FROM myTable 
     WHERE version = @version)
```

But the problem is that this performs quite slow, like more than 10 seconds per operation. What would be the best way to make this operation as fast as lightning? I've already tried selecting into a temp table and merging from there but that didn't do any faster..

Comment: Can you post the plans and row counts?

Comment: row-count 1,5 million rows per one operation. couple of indexes too but i think they are not relevant here as they can be disabled and enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1. Using a temp table is very unlikely to help. That would be magic.
2. Using NOLOCK is very unlikely to help. I cannot see any evidence that this is a blocking  problem because there is only one concurrent transaction (at least on the testing system).
3. Not sure why rebuilding the index is faster that maintaining it. Your table probably has very few versions in it? If you get many the index rebuild is going to get slower and slower. Not a long-term solution.
4. Try changing the clustered index key to (Version, ID) so that inserts are sequential. Random DML is much slower than sequential DML.

Comment: Finally someone with deep knowledge of this stuff! I already have the primary key defined as (Version, ID). Maybe I just have to redesign my things so that I create a new table for each version like [Version_1], [Version_2] and use dynamic SQL in stored procedures to use the data.

Comment: You know, 150k rows per second insert speed is a very good number. You won't be able to make this an order of magnitude faster, that's for sure. Proof: Run an insert into a fresh, empty table with only the CI and measure the speed. This is the max speed you can get. Btw, why do you need to complete a 1.5 million (!) row operation so quickly? Such a thing should be fairly rare?!

Comment: If you really need to optimize this, consider either the solution with multiple tables or partitioning (which is doing exactly that under the hood). That allows you to build new indexes instead of maintaining existing ones.

Comment: Because in my solution there will be 1,5m rows of data, and users make modifications to that data by creating a new version, setting some states to some of the rows and have the ability to go back to older version immediatily if the modifications aren't good. I will go with the solution of multiple tables - with that i get under 5 sec results and maybe that's enough for me :) The reason to optimize this is simply that I like optimizing things to the maximum, no customer request :)

Comment: Ok if you want to go to the maximum for fun you could keep a spare table that is a copy of a fairly recent one. When you want to create a new version, instead of inserting 1.5m rows, you execute a merge statement with insert,update,delete clauses to sync the spare table to the exact state of @version. If only a few rows (10k or so) are modified, this will be much faster. This might give you an order of magnitude increase.(Notice, that the spare table does not need to have any particular state as the merge statement synchronizes it completely.It can have *any* state, the more recent the better)

Comment: Ok, sounds nice, but in this spare / merge situation, how can we go back to some spesific version in time?

Comment: Just use the multi-table scheme that you proposed. I did not mean to have a single table or something. My idea was to just do the normal table-copy that you do when creating a new version. But if a spare table is available you just use that one (and rename it). On a background thread you create a new one after 30s or so. If no spare table is available you just do a normal copy. The spare is meant to be an (optional) optimization for creating a new version. The aim is to keep one (or more) around in a pool, but if the pool is empty you can always fall back to a normal "insert copy".

Comment: Got it, what a great idea! I'll accept your answer even though I didn't get a straight answer to my question, but I appreciate your suggestion and time used for this!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added an index to the version column? That should speed things up.

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_tableName_VERSION ON tableName (version)
```

**UPDATE**

How about using NOLOCK on the table read? Not valid if you believe you could get dirty reads in you system from other transactions against the table. I have had some success using this before, just need to be careful using it!

```
INSERT INTO myTable 
    (SELECT ID, version + 1, somecolumn, anothercolumn, thirdcolumn 
     FROM myTable WITH(NOLOCK)
     WHERE version = @version)
```

Comment: yes there is index, but I believe that in INSERT operations indexes actually makes the inserting performance lower

Comment: I was looking at the select part of the statement. 10 seconds per operation seems excessive so I assumed the version column didn't have an index that was being used in the select part of the query.

Comment: It's the insertion of 1,5 million rows that takes the 10 ~ 15 seconds.. That's why i'm looking for some real fast "Bulk" operation. i calculated that 1,5 million x row size is only something like ~30megabytes, so it shouldn't take that long..

Comment: Maybe use NOLOCK if appropriate? I have updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

```
begin
  SELECT ID, version + 1, somecolumn, anothercolumn, thirdcolumn 
  into #temp
  FROM myTable 
  WHERE version = @version

  ALTER INDEX IDX_tableName_VERSION ON tableName.version DISABLE 

  INSERT INTO myTable
  select * from #temp

  ALTER INDEX IDX_tableName_VERSION ON tableName.version ENABLE 

end
```

Comment: Dropping indexes splits the time taken by half, but #temp table doesn't bring any real performance gain to the actual query. The best results I got (5 sec) is if i just create a new table for each version, but that involves use of some dynamic SQL which isn't so great..

Comment: Can you chk by adding records directly to myTable instead of #Temp after index is disable ?

Comment: Yes, directly to myTable is about 2 seconds slower than using #temp table after disabling indexes